# Python install not behaving like native python

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

My system came with python `2.7.6` and python `3.4.0`. For a project I installed python `3.3.6`. This python installation behaves oddly though. Two tings in particular are strange,

1. It doesn't have the module `zlib`
2. In the terminal when I run python `.2.7.6` I can access the previous command with up and down arrows. In the terminal for python `3.3.6` I instead get weird text, e.g.   `^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[B^[[A`

A quick gif comparing the working (`2.7.6` & `3.4.0`) vs. the non-working (`3.3.6`)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `zlib` is an optional module that isn't compiled when the required libraries are not found.
- readline support is another optional module that isn't compiled when the required libraries are not found.

For Ubuntu, install the build packages for these:

```
aptitude install zlib1g-dev libreadline-dev
```

Other packages that you may want to install that Python 3 depends on:

```
libncursesw5-dev
libssl-dev
libgdbm-dev
libsqlite3-dev
tk-dev
```

Comment: So the dependencies for `zlib` were not found during the install, hence it was not installed? How can I make sure `zlib` and any other modules will be installed?

Comment: @ComradeVader: you did not specify how you installed the Python binary.

Comment: @Martin I installed python 3.3.6 via this answer on http://askubuntu.com/a/244550/207696. I did it the `Compile Python from source` way. The answer install `3.3.5` but I modified the the numbers to fit my needs.

Comment: @Martin I am not using a Mac, I am using Linux Mint 17.1

Comment: @ComradeVader: yeah, not sure why I though that. Corrected.

Comment: @Martin so after I install the build package I have to re install python 3.3.6, but this time it will include the zlib module?

Comment: Yes, you need to reconfigure Python and recompile.